# checked if null before freed all variables, but still get memory error

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, realloc

this is my C programming lab, I've been working on this for two days, still can't figure out what's wrong.

The program should take in user's input from terminal, one is command name, the other is filename, then store them into the corresponding variable, for example:

% Grock- setdb data.txt

(then variable Command stores "setdb", fileName stores "data.txt", Grock- promps again, waiting for user input)

% Grock-

Now if user input is "setdb new.txt"
then variable Command stores "setdb", fileName stores "new.txt"
below is my code, I freed input, command and fileName, and before I freed them, I checked if they are NULL,

But,  valgrind --leak-check=yes 12  still gives below info:
==8701==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

```
red 284 % valgrind --leak-check=yes 12
==8701== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8701== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8701== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8701== Command: 12
==8701== 
==8701== Invalid read of size 1
==8701==    at 0x4C2BFE2: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:460)
==8701==    by 0x4008B7: main (in /eecs/home/lydiaxc/2031/12)
==8701==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==8701== 
==8701== 
==8701== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==8701==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==8701==    at 0x4C2BFE2: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:460)
==8701==    by 0x4008B7: main (in /eecs/home/lydiaxc/2031/12)
==8701==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==8701==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==8701==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==8701==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==8701==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==8701== 
==8701== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8701==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8701==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==8701== 
==8701== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8701== 
==8701== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8701== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

if the inputStr is "setdb hello",  Command is "setdb", fileName is "hello"

however, if inputting the "setdb hello" again, the output becomes:

```
﻿inputStr =  "hellosetdb hello"
Command =
filename=o
free input
free command
12(58215,0x1057e35c0) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fa089402ab0: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x500000000000006f
12(58215,0x1057e35c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

And the output differs from time to time, the crash is unpredictable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * getInput(char* inputStr);
char * getCommand(char* Command, char* inputStr);
char * getFileName(int fileNameLen, int CommandLen, int inputLen, char* inputStr, char* Command, char* fileName);


int main(){
   char *inputStr;
   char *Command;
   char *fileName;
   char *extraFile;
   int inputLen = 0;
   int CommandLen = 0;
   int fileNameLen = 0;

      printf("Grock- ");
      inputStr = getInput(inputStr);
      printf("inputStr = %s\n", inputStr);
      inputLen = (int)strlen(inputStr);
      Command = getCommand(Command, inputStr);
      printf("Command = %s\n", Command);
      CommandLen = (int)( strlen(Command) );
      fileNameLen = inputLen - CommandLen - 1;  //1 is for the space between command and filename
      fileName = getFileName(fileNameLen, CommandLen, inputLen, inputStr, Command, fileName);
      printf("filename=%s\n", fileName);

      while (strcmp("quit", Command)!= 0){   //command != quit
         if ( strcmp(Command, "setdb") == 0 ){
            if ( strlen(fileName) == 0 ){
               printf("Missing Argument.\n");
            }
         } /*if command == setdb */

         if (inputStr){ printf("free input\n"); free(inputStr); inputStr = NULL; }
         if (Command){printf("free command\n");free(Command); Command = NULL;}
         if (fileName){printf("free filename\n"); free(fileName);  fileName = NULL;}

         printf("Grock- ");
         inputStr = getInput(inputStr);
         printf("inputStr = %s\n", inputStr);
         inputLen = (int)strlen(inputStr);
         Command = getCommand(Command, inputStr);
         printf("Command = %s\n", Command);
         CommandLen = (int)(strlen(Command));
         fileNameLen = inputLen- CommandLen- 1;  //1 is for the space
         fileName = getFileName(fileNameLen, CommandLen, inputLen, inputStr, Command, fileName);
         printf("filename=%s\n", fileName);
   }//while

return 0;
} //end programm


char * getInput(char* ainputStr){
   int i = 1;
   char ch[2];   // do not use char* ch; cause segmentation fault
   ch[1] = '\0';    // later for strcat, we need '\0'.
   ainputStr = malloc( (i+1)*sizeof(char) );   //extra 1 memo size is to store '\0'.
   fgets(ch, 2, stdin);  //ch stores 1 char from user input each time, includes the new line char
   while(ch[0] != '\n'){   //ainputStr does not include '\n'
      strcat(ainputStr, ch);    //ainputStr takes the '\0' in ch[1]
      i++;
      ainputStr = realloc(ainputStr, (i+1)* sizeof(char));
      fgets(ch, 2, stdin);   //includes the new line char
   } //while
return ainputStr;
}

char* getCommand(char* aCommand, char* ainputStr)
{
   int i = 1;
   char ch[2];   // do not use char* ch; cause segmentation fault
   ch[1] = '\0';    // later for strcat, we need '\0'.
   aCommand = malloc( (i+1)*sizeof(char) );  // 2 memo unit
   if(aCommand){  // malloc succeeds
      ch[0] = ainputStr[i-1];
      printf("ch[0] = %c\n", ch[0]);
      while(ch[0] != ' ' && ch[0] !='\n'){  // aCommand does not include  space and '\n'
         strncat(aCommand, ch, 1);  //add ch to the end of aCommand
         i++;
     aCommand = realloc(aCommand, (i+1)*sizeof(char));
         ch[0] = ainputStr[i-1];
      }//while
   aCommand[i-1] = '\0';
   }//if
   else{
      printf("Command malloc fails.");
   }
return aCommand;
}


char* getFileName(int fileNameLen, int CommandLen, int inputLen, char* inputStr, char* Command, char* fileName)
{
   int size = 1;
   int start = inputLen - CommandLen-1;
   fileName = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char));
   if(fileName){  //malloc succeeds
      char ch[2];   // do not use char* ch; cause segmentation fault
      ch[1] = '\0';    // later for strcat, we need '\0'.
      ch[0] = inputStr[start];
      while( ch[0] != '\0'){
         strncat(fileName, ch, 1);
         size++; start++;
     fileName = realloc(fileName, (size+1)*sizeof(char));
         ch[0] = inputStr[start];
      }//while
   fileName[size-1] = '\0';
   }//if
   else{
      printf("Command malloc fails.");
   }
return fileName;
}
```

Comment: the `free()` function properly handles being passed a pointer that contains NULL, so no need to check

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`; there are a bunch of errors that the compiler will catch.  Fix those first, there is a good chance it will solve the problem you're asking about, but even if not should be easier to find the problem.

Comment: OT: regarding lines like: `if (Command){printf("free command\n");free(Command); Command = NULL;}`  Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: when calling `fgets()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this statement: `inputStr = getInput(inputStr);` is using an uninitialized parameter: `inputStr`.   this statement: `Command = getCommand(Command, inputStr);` is using an uninitialized parameter: `Command`.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same warnings.

Comment: regarding: `ainputStr = malloc( (i+1)*sizeof(char) );`   1) this will not work to update the value in function: `main()` as the address of the variable in `main()` was not passed.  2) in C, the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1,  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) Suggest removing the `ainputStr` parameter.  4) when calling `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  5)  Suggest: `char * ainputStr = malloc( i+1); if( !ainputStr ) { perror( "malloc failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Command malloc fails.");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, When the error indication is from a C library function should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` exists for that purpose.  I.E.  `perror( "Command malloc fails." );`

Comment: in function: `main()`, regarding: `fileName = getFileName(fileNameLen, CommandLen, inputLen, inputStr, Command, fileName);`  Since the returned value may be `NULL`, the function `main()` needs to check for this and not proceed as if it does have a file name available.